# Accessing Virtual Server 2005 RC2 hosted machines using IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, microsoft-virtual-server

I'm trying to access some hosted WinXP machines inside Virtual Server 2005 RC2 using IE8 (via the ActiveX control in the web admin page), but when I do the mouse cursor behave erratically. A tiny movement of the mouse moves the cursor from one side of the virtual screen to the other, making it impossible to use the mouse.

Is there a way round this, or do I just have to make sure I use an older version IE8 to access these virtual machines?

I'm already using IE8 Compatibility View, and I've tried this from a few machines (Vista and Windows 7 so far) running IE8 and had the same problem on each. Sometimes it looks as though the mouse cursor isn't visible, but I think that's because it's locked up against the right (or bottom) of the screen of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

Wilka,

The Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 web admin page needs to be displayed in "Compatibility View" mode in IE8. None of the drop down selectors were working for me until I added the site into this view mode i.e. Known Image Files drop down in CD / Media capture window wasn't selecting my choices.

I haven't experienced the erratic mouse behaviour with IE8, even without Compatibility View mode enabled. This sounds like the "Virtual Machine Additions" are not installed. You can check whether they are and what version (if any) is applied.

"Edit Configuration" for the machine you want to check > Check the entry next to "Virtual Machine Additions" > You should have something like version 13.820. This is what shows on an x64 implementation of VServer 2005 R2 on a server I am running.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm already using Compatibility View - it didn't work at all without that.

Comment: OK, have you confirmed that you have the Virtual Machine Additions installed?

Comment: Compatibility View helped me with a similar issue - the dropdown actions weren't working and I was getting JavaScript errors. Thanks.